# Can't make transaction in class

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, drawer

I have Main activity:

```
public class GeneralActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
...
}
```

I have another class in which I create a drawer, I bring to the required parameters. But when I want to move to a different fragment when you click on the menu item, then IDE writes that there is no method getSupportFragmentManager ().

```
public class DrawerClass {

    public static void drawer(final Activity activity, Toolbar toolbar) {
    ...
    result.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemClick(View view, int i, IDrawerItem iDrawerItem) {
                Log.d("POSITION", "position = " + i);
                switch (i) {
                ....
                    case 5:
                        Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.drawer_item_journal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        JournalFragment journalFragment = new JournalFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.profile_fragment_layout, journalFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I have an error on the line `FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()` And I don't know how fix it. 
I use this drawer in several classes, so I created a separate class in order to avoid duplication of code

Answer (score 0):

you cant use getSupportFragmentManager outside of Activity or Fragment..
so do

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

plus an advice to you change it from Static to Singleton..

Comment: AndroidStudio say that activity have only getFragmentManager()

Comment: then you need to use Activity from v4 support package and not activity from high API check your imports